# CSS rendering of Bullet List menu in Chrome and Safari

Tags: asp.net, css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

The is a problem in rendering my menu inside Chrome

**The Image :**

***Edit :***
I was right, The problem was exactly related to rendering Asp.Net bulletin list Control, and not the HTML ! And it should be called as one of the bugs of Google Chrome. 
Somebody deleted the Asp.Net tag wrongly, so I added it again,
***I think maybe one change in CSS could make it understandable for the WebKit browsers, a hack a trick, or something similar could help***

***The source will work as expected in Firfox 8+ and IE 9 as I tested, but the menu will drop one step down in Chrome and Safari (WebKit) !***
Here You have the details,
any helps is greatly appreciated

The menu uses Asp.Net Bulletin List Control

**This is the Code :**

```
<div id="mainmenu">
    <asp:BulletedList  id="nav" Runat="server" DisplayMode="HyperLink" Target="_self" EnableViewState="false">
        <asp:ListItem 
            Text="Home"
            Value="" />
        <asp:ListItem 
            Text="Contact Us"
            Value="#" />
        <asp:ListItem 
            Text="About Us"
            Value="#" />
    </asp:BulletedList>
</div>
```

**Using DevTools in Chrome will show a **Gap*** under the menu div :*

```
<div id="mainmenu">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="default.aspx" target="_self">Home</a></li><li><a href="contact.aspx" target="_self">Contact Us</a></li><li><a href="about.aspx" target="_self">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here as you can see there is a gap (Just viewable via the DevTools ),
when I remove this gap the rendering issue will be disappeared .
It's source via "view source" seems normal ...

**Edit - The Generated HTML COde :**

```
<div id="mainmenu">
```

"
                    "

Home

Contact Us

About Us

**At Last** 
If I change the bullet List simply to the below code, It'll work on them :

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="../default.aspx">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="../contact.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="../about.aspx">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please post HTML code instead of ASP code - this is an HTML issue, not ASP.

Comment: I added the generated HTML via Chrome

Comment: The Problem was not the HTML, Was just rendering the Bullet List...

Comment: No help ? anyone experienced ? What is in the asp.net translated version that couldn't be rendered correctly by Webkit Browsers ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it has something to do with those extra quotes inside your #mainmenu `div`. Can you tell where those are coming from?

Comment: I want to know that also, using "view source" it shows it the normal way, but the DevTools shows an extra gap

Comment: I don't know anything about ASP, but is it possible to format that little ASP snippet so that it's all on one line?  If you can, and it renders correctly, it may be an issue with some kind of invisible characters.  I'd try eliminating all the whitespace from that ASP snippet, and if that works, then adding the whitespace back in by hand and testing again.